# Getting unknown type 'FriendList' error when accessing Facebook module-ballerina

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I'm trying to get FriendLists from Facebook module-ballerina (Ballerina version- 0.990.2). But I'm getting unknown type 'FriendList' error. How can I overcome this error?

```
FriendList friendList = {};
var response = facebookclient->getFriendListDetails("");
if (response is FriendList) {
     friendList = response;
} else {
     test:assertFail(msg = <string>response.detail().message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the name of the module before the `FriendList` record as `facebook:FriendList`.

```
facebook:FriendList friendList = {};
var response = facebookclient->getFriendListDetails("");
if (response is facebook:FriendList) {
     friendList = response;
} else {
     test:assertFail(msg = <string>response.detail().message);
}
```